# How to bundle lazy loaded components inside the production dist folder in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-cli

I am using `angular-cli` for development and I have used the following commands and code to build my project.

`npm install angular-cli` (angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10)

`ng new my-app`

`ng g component lazy-me`

Then added a file `app.router.ts` with the following script

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// import { LazyMeComponent } from './+lazy-me/lazy-me.component';

const appRoutes : RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
//   {path: 'lazyme', component: LazyMeComponent}
  {path: 'lazyme', component: 'app/+lazy-me#LazyMeComponent'}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER = [
    provideRouter(appRoutes)
];
```

And changed my main.ts as following

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode,
    SystemJsComponentResolver, 
    ComponentResolver } from '@angular/core';
import {RuntimeCompiler} from '@angular/compiler';
import { AppComponent, environment } from './app/';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER } from './app/app.router';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDER,
  {
    provide: ComponentResolver,
    useFactory: (r) => new SystemJsComponentResolver(r),
    deps: [RuntimeCompiler]
  },
]);
```

And to do a production build I have used the following command
`ng build -prod`

When I deploy my code to a webserver and navigate to `lazyme` path, I get 404 error for `app/lazy-me/lazy-me.component.js`

The folder exists but `lazy-me.component.js` is missing as expected as everything gets bundled in `main.js` except .css and .html files.
However, I want `ng build -prod` to include `lazy-me.component.js` in `dist/app/lazy-me/`.

Is there any settings in `system-config.ts` or anywhere else where I can include lazy loaded components to be part of the `dist` folder when doing a `-prod` build?

Comment: Hello Gan did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I could not achieve it with the old angular-cli. However if you use latest angular-cli with webpack, and add routes with new syntax of lazy loading (`loadChildren` attribute in Routes), we can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your 'lazy' component is not actually loaded lazily in your router configuration. First, you need to wrap it in its own module, which you want to load lazily. Then, you need the 'loadChildren' property in your router configuration to refer to that module, rather than referring to the component directly.

This article might shed some more light onto the entire issue, hope it doesn't go stale and helps: https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee

Also, to debug issues like this: if you are willing to upgrade your version of Angular CLI to at least beta.32, they have added an 'eject' command similar to create-react-app. Using that, you get access to the webpack config file. Using this, you can change the production build to fit your needs, if the default CLI is not working as expected. I'm aware this is kind of a work-around though. Good luck!